# conditional format rows in power bi based on measure

Tags: powerbi

How i can write the measure to trigger conditional format a row which has column named "Header IND" = Yes. I would like to change the background for that row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create a calculated column based on values YES, NO
[image]

Next do conditional formatting for each column colA, colB, Header IND
[image]

Comment: Hi Ashok, Thank you for answer. somehow the expression does not work column = If(Data[Header IND]= "Yes", 1,2). it does not recognize the column name Header IND. i have to change to column = If(min(Data[Header IND])= "Yes", 1,2) then it recognize the column name. but i don't want to look for min(Data[Header IND]). Help.

Comment: The expression column = If(Data[Header IND]= "Yes", 1,2) should work.  Post the error you are getting.